# CSS - How to hide the 4th <li> without CSS class on WP Admin menu

Tags: css, wordpress, list, html-lists

I have tried to hide the 4th

in a Wordpress Admin menu without luck.

1. I have tried to access 4th

   without success. Here are my codes:

   ```
    HTML codes:

    <ul class="wp-submenu wp-submenu-wrap">
      <li class="wp-submenu-head" aria-hidden="true">Media</li>
      <li class="wp-first-item"><a href="upload.php" class="wp-first-item">Library</a></li>
      <li><a href="media-new.php">Add New</a></li>
      <li><a href="upload.php?page=webpc_optimization_page">Converter for Media</a></li>
    </ul>


    CSS codes:

      li.wp-submenu:nth-child(4) {
        display: none;
      }

    OR:
      li.wp-submenu-wrap:nth-child(4) {
        display: none;
      }
   ```
2. I have also tried to hide it using PHP codes. Here is its link:

   ```
    URL:

    https://www.mywebsite.net/admin-cpanel/upload.php?page=webpc_optimization_page

    php codes:

    add_action( 'admin_init', 'hide_admin_menu_items' );
    function hide_admin_menu_items() {
         global $user_ID;
        if ( $user_ID != 1 ) {
          remove_menu_page('webpc_admin_page');      // Converter for media         // not working
      }
    }
   ```

Please advise how to hide that 4th

from WP Admin menu.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had the CSS wrong. `li` doesn't have class `wp-submenu`

```css
ul.wp-submenu li:nth-child(4) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="wp-submenu wp-submenu-wrap">
  <li class="wp-submenu-head" aria-hidden="true">Media</li>
  <li class="wp-first-item"><a href="upload.php" class="wp-first-item">Library</a></li>
  <li><a href="media-new.php">Add New</a></li>
  <li><a href="upload.php?page=webpc_optimization_page">Converter for Media</a></li>
</ul>
```